# Deleting a record within a binary file?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I've been messing around with binary files the last whole week. One thing I can't figure out how to do is selectively delete a record from the binary file. 
Is this possible in c++? If not, what are ways in which you can do this.

I'm contemplating, maybe creating a duplicate file without the record inside, but that would seem rather inefficient for very large data files. Any more efficient ways, or any way of duplicating a file efficiently? I''m surprised there's ways to delete files, but not selectively delete from a file.

Comment: You could include a deletion marker in each record. This is how many database servers operate; deleted records are just marked as deleted and the space is reused for another record later (or the space is reclaimed when the relevant table is optimized/compacted/vacuumed).

Comment: What do you expect when you `delete a record` -- the answer depends on what you expect to happen with space occupied by the record that you have deleted.

Comment: @cdhowie That's an interesting idea. Time to research how to implement this perfectly.

Comment: Alternatively you can keep an index of live/deleted records. The index can be very compact as you only need one *`bit`* per record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike data structures in memory, you can't pull out a record from a file. You have to:

1. Read the contents of the file into an in-memory data structure
2. Remove the relevant data from the data structure in-memory.
3. Write the updated data structure back to the file.

Comment: I see, thanks for the information. I'll definitely keep this in mind, and will try a few of the things listed here. This, and marking them as deleted sound interesting.

Comment: @ReMaKe, you are welcome. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure ever record have a flag "deleted" which you set to false when you first write the record, but then change to true if you want to mark the record deleted.